# How to check did laravel update a table?

Tags: php, laravel-5.3

Below I need to update some columns in the users table. I use laravel query builder in code. I want to know if users table got updated or not?

```
 DB::table('users')
            ->where('id',2)
            ->update
            ([
                'first_name'            => trim($validate->firstName),
                'capital'               => trim($validate->capital),
                'last_name'             => trim($validate->lastName),
                'town'                  => trim($validate->town),
                'visit_price'           => trim($validate->visit),
                'consultant_account'    => trim($validate->account),
                'grade'                 => trim($validate->grade),
                'tel'                   => trim($validate->tel),
                'mobile'                => trim($validate->mobile),
                'expert'                => trim($validate->expert),
                'password'              => ($validate->pass),

            ]);
```

Comment: Laravel model and table record in DB are different things. In most cases, there is better to use the model

Comment: did not get your point

Comment: I think better use https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent#updates, then 
https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queries#updates. ORM features more useful.

Comment: aha...yeah you are right...since I used query builder  every time somehow I got use to that.by the way TNX

Comment: @Arash.shire, I have edited your question.

Comment: @galkin, Thank so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check like this:

```
$update = DB::table('users')
            ->where('id',2)
            ->update
            ([
                'first_name'            => trim($validate->firstName),
                'capital'               => trim($validate->capital),
                'last_name'             => trim($validate->lastName),
                'town'                  => trim($validate->town),
                'visit_price'           => trim($validate->visit),
                'consultant_account'    => trim($validate->account),
                'grade'                 => trim($validate->grade),
                'tel'                   => trim($validate->tel),
                'mobile'                => trim($validate->mobile),
                'expert'                => trim($validate->expert),
                'password'              => ($validate->pass),

            ]);

if($update !== false){
//updated
}
else
{
//Not updated
}
```

Comment: tick that @lalithk umar